# Displaying related table column name in listview

Tags: yii, dataprovider

I have a simple database with 2 tables: tbl_code and tbl_user

```
**tbl_code**
id(PK)
accesscode
createdby(FK references tbl_user.id)
accesstime

**tbl_user**
id (PK)
username
password
```

I am trying to display the following in listview

- id (tbl_code.id)
- accesscode
- createdby - (With this displaying the username from the user table)
- accesstime

Current controller:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Code');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
```

Index view

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

and finally _view

```
<div class="view">

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id), array('view', 'id'=>$data->id)); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('accesscode')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->accesscode); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('createdby')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->createdby); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('accesstime')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->accesstime); ?>
    <br />

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('messagecount')); ?>:</b>
    <?php echo CHtml::encode($data->messagecount); ?>
    <br />


</div>
```

Should I be joining these two tables in the $dataprovider criteria or is there a better way to achieve this?
Still getting to grips with Yii, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could miss a lot of thinks in your code so I'll show some of the thing you'll need:

**In the models**

In your model you need to indicate the relation that exists.

In `User` you need to define the relation that link this model to the code

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'codes'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Code', 'createdby'),
    );
}
```

And in `Code` you'll have

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'author'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'createdby'),
    );
}
```

Now the models can be linked when callign them in the controllers or the views

**The Data Provider**

In the data provider we will indicate the releted model that need to be loaded while loading code:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Code', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'with'=>array('author'),
    ),
));
```

**The View**

Now in the view yiou can display the author:

```
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->author->getAttributeLabel('username')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->author->username); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I had generated the models from the gii tool
The relations() on the code model was:

`public function relations()`
 `{`
  `return array(`
   `'createdby' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblUser', 'createdby'),`
  `);`
 `}`

and the relations() on the user model was: 
`public function relations()`
 `{`
  `return array(`
   `'tblCodes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TblCode', 'createdby'),`
  `);`
 `}`
 
which I noticed pointed to the wrong filenames. i.e TblUser was User and TblCode was Code in my case. 
But got it working. Thanks!